# Click handler being invoked twice on same element

Tags: javascript

I have two div elements, `inner` and `outer`. I am triggering click event on `inner` div programmatically only once. But the log shows that the event handler is invoked twice on `inner` div. Here is the code. Can you please help understand why is this happening. Code is also hosted on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-wildflower-kuf3sp)

```js
const inner = document.querySelector(".inner");
const outer = document.querySelector(".outer");
    
function clk(event) {
  console.log("click");
  console.log(event.target);
}
    
inner.addEventListener("click", clk);
outer.addEventListener("click", clk);
    
inner.click();
```

```html
<div class="outer" id="div1">
  <div class="inner" id="div2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just like the answers state, it's due to event bubbling. If you want to prevent that from happening you can use `event.stopPropagation()`.

Comment: note also that if you logged `event.currentTarget` instead of `event.target1, you'd see the "outer" div for the second log - `currentTarget` is always the element the event handler was added to, while `target` is the actual element that the event was triggered on originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of [Event bubbling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_bubbling_and_capture).

What's happening is :

1. You tigger the `click` event on `inner`.
2. The event listener of `inner` is called.
3. The `click` event bubbles up to outer.
4. The event listener of `outer` is called

The target is `inner` in both calls to the `clk` function, because it's a property of the initial event. It doesn't depend on the element the listener is registered on.

Answer (score 4):

add

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

to your clk function

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you subscribe on outer as well as on inner because of event bubbling effect which is presented in JavaScript(see: https://javascript.info/bubbling-and-capturing).
That`s why it is executed on inner and outer element - you added handler for both:

```
inner.addEventListener("click", clk);
outer.addEventListener("click", clk);
```

Answer (score 1):

The event is only triggered once per element. You can see this if you use the [currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) rather than the [target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

```
function clk(event) {
  console.log("click");
  console.log(event.currentTarget);
}
```